# SharePoint 2013- Anonymous users not able to read from Termstore

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, jsom, term-store

I have a public facing anonymous site in SharePoint 2013 on Premise. I have written some JSOM to read terms from Termstore .For authenticated users this works fine but for Anonymous users , it throws access denied. 
Below are some configurations of the site:

1. Whole site collection is anonymous enabled.
2. Require Use Remote Interfaces permission is disabled.
3. Taxonomy hidden list is also set to anonymous.

Note: I am not using Managed Metadata Navigation.

**Update**: This seems to be a limitation of SharePoint that anonymous users cannot access terms directly from MMS using JSOM . Workaround is to read it from Taxonomy hidden list.

Answer (score -2):

Go into Term Store, select the term and specify a target page for the item, the path to the anonymous page that uses the term.

Also

Navigate to the hidden list at /lists/TaxonomyHiddenList and check the permissions. If necessary grant read to All Authenticated Users/everyone.

Comment: I am not using Managed Metadata navigation, so there is no option to specify Target page.